# Check Starting Form Values For JavaScript Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have an HTML form that I already validate using Javascript. However, I am only checking to make sure it has been filled out. I also need to check to be sure that the first eight characters of the form do not contain "FFFFFFFF" or "ffffffff". It will be a 40 character input into the form field. I am just not sure how to do this with Javascript.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var txt = document.getElementById('id').value;
var first = txt.substring(0,8);
if(first=="FFFFFFFF"||first=="ffffffff"){
  // validation error
else
  //validation success
```

as simple as that. i can't be more specific since you haven't shared any of your code.